# python naive Bayes tutorial - what is two_obs_test[continuous_list]?

Tags: python, naivebayes

I'm following a tutorial on Naive Bayes at https://towardsdatascience.com/why-how-to-use-the-naive-bayes-algorithms-in-a-regulated-industry-with-sklearn-python-code-dbd8304ab2cf but I'm stuck on interpreting the reference in the third code block to `two_obs_test[continuous_list]`

The full code listing is ...

```
# Observation_0
gssnX15p0 = (1/((2*np.pi*gssnX15var0)**0.5))*np.exp((-(two_obs_test[continuous_list].iloc[0,0]-gssnX15mean0)**2)/(2*gssnX15var0))
gssnX15p1 = (1/((2*np.pi*gssnX15var1)**0.5))*np.exp((-(two_obs_test[continuous_list].iloc[0,0]-gssnX15mean1)**2)/(2*gssnX15var1))

gssnX16p0 = (1/((2*np.pi*gssnX16var0)**0.5))*np.exp((-(two_obs_test[continuous_list].iloc[0,1]-gssnX16mean0)**2)/(2*gssnX16var0))
gssnX16p1 = (1/((2*np.pi*gssnX16var1)**0.5))*np.exp((-(two_obs_test[continuous_list].iloc[0,1]-gssnX16mean1)**2)/(2*gssnX16var1))

gssnX18p0 = (1/((2*np.pi*gssnX18var0)**0.5))*np.exp((-(two_obs_test[continuous_list].iloc[0,2]-gssnX18mean0)**2)/(2*gssnX18var0))
gssnX18p1 = (1/((2*np.pi*gssnX18var1)**0.5))*np.exp((-(two_obs_test[continuous_list].iloc[0,2]-gssnX18mean1)**2)/(2*gssnX18var1))
```

I can't find a two_obs_test in the sklearn library and very little turns up when I google it.  What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial has too many gaps.  I think a view of the insides of Naive Bayes without reading a whole book is better found at https://machinelearningmastery.com/naive-bayes-classifier-scratch-python/ .  I am not persisting with the tutorial and I advise others to avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

two_obs_test[continuous_list] doesn't refer to anything coming from the sklearn library. It is just the name of the example database that you can find as a picture on this link:
[link_of_the_database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/darMK.png)

continuous_list refers to the continuous columns name that are ['X15', 'X16', 'X18'] and has a result, two_obs_test[continuous_list].iloc[0,0] refers to the first observation in Figure 1 for the variable X15 having the value -0.852371

I didn't find on any other places someone explaining step by step how each of the sklearn's NB were working, this is the reason why this tutorial exists !